# How add spacing after of \paragraph

Tags: paragraphs

How add spacing after of \paragraph{Parrafo}?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand\paragraph[1]{$\bullet$ \textbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{ } %if you want a name write it as \chapter{name}
init
\section{seccion}
\paragraph{Parrafo} this is a paragraph 

this is not paragraph (
and should not have a bullet)
\section{ seccion}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

When I put the **bullet** the spacing was reduced, now I want to increase the spacing.

Comment: `\paragraph` is one of the document division commands used after `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`. Better to create something called, say, `\mypara` which does what you want instead of subverting the regular `\paragraph` command.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of redefining `\paragraph` from scratch, you can copy the definition from `report.cls` and add your `\bullet`:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
    {4mm}% <-- Space _before_ the paragraph title
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
    {-1em}% <-- Space _after_ the paragraph title (with a minus sign)
    %                               V--------V added this to the original
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries$\bullet$~}% Content before the paragraph title
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{seccion}
\paragraph{Parrafo} this is a paragraph 

this is not paragraph (%
and should not have a bullet)
\section{seccion}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i want also space before of paragraph %\renewcommand\paragraph[1]{$\bullet$\hspace{4mm}\textbf{#1}}

Comment: @x-rw I changed to add the `4mm` before the paragraph title as you asked.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I could be wrong every one seems to be helping x-rw vertically ? I think request for before paragraph means horizontal offsets

Comment: @KJO Perhaps you're right... I _assumed_ horizontal space because in the question OP said "When I put the bullet the spacing was reduced" which, in my interpretation means the horizontal space between the title and the following text. Also, in OP's comment right above they said "`$\bullet$\hspace{4mm}\textbf{#1}`", with an `\hspace`. We can only hope that OP will leave a comment clarifying :)

Comment: Sorry scratch my comment above looking closer this thread is correctly addressing space either side of paragraph Tag  what confused me was the moving word alignment relative to second line.